# java mmap in hugetlbfs

Tags: java, mmap

I am moving a Java project to use hugetlbfs in Linux, I use mmap to read/write files in hugetlbfs, I found 2 weird things:
1. The file size in hugetlbfs must be a multiple of page size
2. You cannot use Cleaner to unmap a MappedByteBuffer which mapped from a hugetlbfs file. It says GC will take care of the clean, so I leave it unmmaped, but then I sometimes run to this error

```
`java.lang.Error: Cleaner terminated abnormally
    at sun.misc.Cleaner$1.run(Cleaner.java:147)
    at sun.misc.Cleaner$1.run(Cleaner.java:144)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.Cleaner.clean(Cleaner.java:144)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:141)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.unmap0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.access$000(FileChannelImpl.java:40)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$Unmapper.run(FileChannelImpl.java:787)
    at sun.misc.Cleaner.clean(Cleaner.java:142)`
```

I don't know where the Cleaner is called, because I never call Cleaner.clean in my code, can anyone help me debug this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in hugetlbfs.

Comment: I found out that it is because of "Invalid argument", the mmap start and length must be a multiple of page size

Comment: I would post this as an answer.